# Quiet hours time picker does not respect 24-hour format setting

Tags: bug, android-app

On Settings - Quiet hours, I get a watch face at 9 (pm) by default. In my 5.1.1 stock Android the 'Use 24-hour format' is set and used by other apps.

[image: screenshot]

It's kind of disconcerting why anybody wants a quiet time at 9, so I thought I have pushed the wrong button. On second, more careful tap, I noticed the subdued gray PM and all become clear. It's more of a paper cut, but annoying.

Comment: `On second, more careful tap, I noticed the subdued gray PM and all become clear. It's more of a paper cut, but annoying.` I read that a couple of times, and still have no idea what it means. Would you care to enlighten me? Also, what are "quiet hours"?

Comment: @Jashaszun which part is unclear? Seems OK to me. In the Android app, you can set quiet hours when you don't get notifications. So you can go to bed and not get woken up by someone making a comment on your question/answer.

Comment: @DavidG I'm talking about the `subdued gray PM` that I don't see in the picture, and the `paper cut`. What does this question have to do with paper cuts?

Comment: @Jashaszun 'Subdued' refers to the colour of the AM/PM text in the image. And as for paper cut, that's just a metaphor for something annoying but ultimately not a disaster.

Comment: @Jashaszun: *paper cut* is an English idiom expressing annoyance.

Comment: @DavidG OHHHHH I thought "PM" stood for "Personal Message", not the *time* PM... this question makes so much more sense now. Thanks! I was just wondering what "subdued gray personal message" everyone could find in the picture that I couldn't.

Comment: Why is it "disconcerting" to want quiet time at 9am?

Comment: @Leonardo Please post this to the SE Meta, as it is about the SE (general) app. At least, that is my opinion.

Comment: [a paper cut bug is defined as "a trivially fixable usability bug that the average user would encounter on his/her first day of using a brand new installation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_cut_bug)

Comment: It’s an analogue clock face. ***It’s a graphic!*** That means you get twelve hours twice a day whether you like it or not. You cannot expect them to change their graphics to suit a decimal display. This is therefore not a bug.

Comment: @tchrist On Android (at least >5.0), if you have the 'Use 24-format' setting on, the watch show two concentric circles, one from 00 to 11 and another from 12 to 23.  The one including the current time is bold, but you can tap values on the other ring too.